Spring JPA filtration and setting
New to java development. Using Spring Boot and Spring JPA to develop a web app.
We have the following data model.
Student - ID, Name, Grade
Course - ID, Name
StudentCourse - ID, StudentID, CourseID, StartDate, Status
StudentAttendance - ID, StudentID, CourseDate, AttendaanceDate, Status
StudentCourseGrade - ID, StudentID, Attempt, CompletionDate, Grade
There are a few more tables as well. All the tables will have StudentID as the referential key.
Have created JPA repository for all the tables. We use single sign on for the student logon. Hence the StudentID will be available in the context. After logon, the student should query only his own data. For example, when the student queries the courses (StudentCourse), he should be able to view only his own courses. Also, when a student joins a new course (StudentCourse), the StudentID should be automatically applied. This is applicable to all tables containing StudentID. What is the best way to implement this in a generic way for all the tables containing StudentID? Pointers to documentation will also be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Have used hibernate @FilterDef and @Filter to achieve this.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

To ensure that students can only fetch their own data securely using Spring Security and Spring Data JPA, you can create a repository method that leverages the authenticated user’s ID. For instance, you can define a query in your repository interface like:
 Query("""SELECT p FROM Book b WHERE 
 p.studentId=?#{authentication.name}
 """ 
 List<Book> findBooks();

This query uses the authenticated user’s ID (retrieved from the security context) to fetch only the records associated with that student. By configuring Spring Security to handle authentication and authorization, and using this repository method in your service or controller, you ensure that each student can only access their own data, maintaining data privacy and security. ( for more info you can see about method level security using Filter)
